# JQuery: Re-size and re-position all child DIVs as parent DIVs is re-sized

Tags: jquery, positioning, draggable, autoresize

In the HTML below
**rootDiv =** Scrollable div as overflow is set to auto
**imageDiv =** JQuery resizable applied on this div
**mainImage =** Contains an image that is resized as 'imageDiv' is resized
**annContainer =** Contains dynamically created DIVs and JQuery 'draggable' applied to each one   of them. These are annotations or tags that can be dragged and placed at a specific position on the image

**Question:** 
When user re-sizes imageDiv the image inside it re-sizes (zoom in or zoom out) fine. Is there a way to auto re-position and re-size the dynamically created DIVs within annContainer as imageDiv is re-sized?

Any help is really appreciated - thanks

```
<div id="rootDiv" class="root-div">
    <div id="imageDiv" class="image-div">
        <img id="mainImage" class="main-image"/>
        <div id="annContainer" class="ann-container"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to handle this yourself.  On a side note, `div` tags should always have a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just resize te rootDiv whenever you are chaning image-div's size

```
function changeImageSize(){
$('#imageDiv').width(300);
// Now simply changge the rootdiv's imae size
$('#rootDiv').width(350);//or someother value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess cannot re-size rootDiv as its size should be constant supporting scrolling (if required)